# API url is being encoded with &amp; instead of just &

Tags: php, json, api, error-handling

I'm trying to connect my app up to an API using this code:

```
class PostcodePrice{
    public function getPrice($postcodes){           
        $apikey = "MYAPIKEY";
        $priceurl = "http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/area_value_graphs.js?area=".$postcodes."&output_type=outcode&api_key=".$apikey;

        $price = file_get_contents($priceurl);
        $decoded = json_decode($price);
        return $decoded->result;
    }
}
```

Now the problem I'm having is my url is being passed to the api and replacing my & with & so my url is looking like this:

```
http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/area_value_graphs.js?area="postcode&amp;output_type=outcode&amp;api_key=MYAPIKEY
```

The API I am using refuses the url with the encoded & so it obviously doesn't work as I get 403's back as a response.

I've tried things such as string replace, htmlspecialchars etc.

Anyone know of how I can stop this from happening?

Comment: Did you post the complete code? I see now reason why `&` would be converted to `&amp;` in what you've posted.

Comment: how do you know it's being converted? Are you sure the conversion isn't being performed as part of logging on the serverside? There is nothing in your posted code that would auto-encode it

Comment: 403 means that you are trying to access Forbidden web page , it isn't related to your url.

Comment: Did you notice the double quote after `area="` in the _looking like this_ part?

Answer (score -1):

U can make "$priceurl" url without concatenation like this.

$priceurl = "http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/area_value_graphs.js?area=$postcodes&output_type=outcode&api_key=$apikey";

Hope it's work for u.